# Etcdctl cuts JSON quotes after put command

Tags: etcd, etcdctl

I'm trying to change my whole json object using etcdctl:

```
etcdctl put /var/dir "{"key1" : "value1", "key2": "value2"}"
```

And after this idk how, but this json become invalid, quotes are cutted:

```
etcdctl get /var/dir
{key1 : value1, key2: value2}
```

How can i avoid this problem?

Comment: Is this a shell command? If so, you need to escape the quotes so that the shell does not remove them, e.g. by enclosing the whol string in single quotes `'`

Comment: Yes, I'm using gitbash terminal, just tryed to use single quotes and get: bash: {keys:: command not found

Answer (score -1):

As @Gereon mentioned, you need to use bracketing single quotes to pass JSON to etcd.   (The same is true in using JSON with `curl`).   The JSON spec calls for double quotes, so you need to ensure you keep valid double quote pairs within the JSON - containing the entire JSON with double quotes messes that up.

The command `etcdctl put /var/dir "{"key1" : "value1", "key2": "value2"}"`, when passed to etcd will not be understood as JSON - etcd will put a single string into the value, which is what you're seeing when you `etcdctl get`

Now surround your JSON with a matched pair of single quotes:

`$ etcdctl put /var/dir '{"key1" : "value1", "key2": "value2"}'`

and you'll see the difference more obviously:

`$ etcdctl get /var/dir`

```
/var/dir
{"key1" : "value1", "key2": "value2"}
```